# Fictitious jQuery persist method

Tags: jquery, methods, selector, persist

Is there a way to have a declaration such as the following persist to all matching elements that are later added to the DOM?

```
$("a.my-class").replaceWith("<span>Replaced</span>");
```

Something along the lines of...

```
$("a.my-class").persist().replaceWith("<span>Replaced</span>");
```

(Persist is a fictitious method, that I hope conveys what I would like to accomplish.)

Comment: Still not sure I completely understand. If (in theory) persist did exist in the way you describe, then your second call would empty it!

Comment: So you would rather I say it like this?

$(".my-class").persist(function(){$(this).replaceWith("<span>Replaced</span>")});

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a method exactly like what you want, but if the content is being added using the jQuery AJAX methods, you can use this:

```
$("<div></div>").ajaxSuccess(function(){
   $("a.my-class").replaceWith("<span>Replaced</span>");
});
```

And this code will run after **every** successful AJAX request, provided the requests are made using a jQuery `$.ajax` call (including `$.post` or `$.get`). You only need to call this once on your page and it will trigger on any AJAX call made.

If you run into trouble with the replacement happening too soon:

```
$("<div></div>").ajaxSuccess(function(){
   window.setTimeout( function(){
       $("a.my-class").replaceWith("<span>Replaced</span>");
   }, 250);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method in jquery does something similar but it is for events.

You could possibly use live() and the load event to achieve what you are looking for, something like (untested):

```
$("a.my-class").live('load',function(){
  $(this).replaceWith("<span>Replaced</span>");
});
```

Comment: There is no page reload to base an event off of. DOM elements are being added via AJAX.

Comment: The above adds a load event load to the element you add via AJAX ('a.my-class'), not the page load.  As I said tho it's untested.